# Disable selection in datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using Primefaces 5.3, and I'm filling a datatable with some records from the database if the length of records is lower than 10 I complete it with empty records so the datatable always diplays 10 rows.

My datatable looks like this :

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable"
   editable="true" editMode="cell"
   value="#{beanPlanningl.getListPlanningSalle(entry, 1)}"
   var="planning"
   selectionMode="single"
   selection="#{beanPlanning.selectedPlanning}"
   rowKey="#{planning.id}"
   sortBy="#{planning.heureDebut}"
   >
```

So what I want is to disable selection on rows that has the empty records.

How can I do that ?

PS : `planning.id` equals 0 in empty records.

## Edit :

I forgot to mention that I already used `rendered` as following :

```
<p:column >
  <p:cellEditor rendered="#{planning.id != 0}">
      <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{planning.heureDebut}" /></f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
          <p:inputMask mask="99:99" value="#{planning.heureDebut}"
                       required="true" maxlength="4"
                       requiredMessage="Heure de début : vous devez indiquer une valeur."
                       validatorMessage="Heure de début non valide.">
              <f:validateRegex pattern="([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"/>
          </p:inputMask>
      </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

But this only prevents from editing cells, but they can be always selected.

## Edit 2 :

I tried to use `disabledSelection` now I can't select rows but cells can always be selected, before I used `disabledSelection` :

[image]

as you can see I can select rows and on hovering they get colored.

and then when I used `disabledSelection` :

[image]

Now hovering doesnt work for empty rows and selection on rows as well, but the cells can always be selected, so no I only need to prevent that from hapenning.

I noticed that when the cell is selected two css classes are added : `ui-state-highlight ui-cell-editing`.

Comment: did you try to add `rendred` to your `dataTable` ?!?

Comment: it will be like that `rendered="#{YourManagedBean.yourCondition}"` do not forget to update the `dataTable` if you change the `rendred` condition value

Comment: @YagamiLight yes I did otherwise my cells would be editable, when I used rendred I prevent editing cells but I can still select them.

Comment: @YagamiLight please check my edit

Comment: did you try `disabledSelection` ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight no I havent, how can I do it ?

Comment: `disabledSelection` work like `rendred` but it disable the checkbox of selection with a certaine condition let assume that your condition is a year `disabledSelection="#{xxx.year > 1960}"`

Comment: @YagamiLight please check my edit

Comment: Simply don't add those empty records. Just add a record if you need an extra record. That will save you hacking everything and will get you a simpler UI.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I need the datatable to always display 10 rows, the only problem i have is when using rendered to hide the `cellEditor`, the cell keeps the behaviour of a cellEditor when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I did was to prevent the default behaviour of columns which doesnt have a `.ui-cell-editor` in it's childs as following :

```
$(".ui-editable-column").click(function(event){
                    if(!$(this).find('.ui-cell-editor').length){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;   
                    }
            });
```